# Differential form on a cone

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry

Consider a set $\xi_1...\xi_k$ of tanget vectors to $\Bbb R^n$ at a point $\mathbf x$.

I was told that the following integral
$$\int_0^1 \omega_{t_x} (\mathbf x, t\xi_1...t\xi_k) dt$$

evaluates the differential form $\omega$ on a cone. I could not "see" it, and, moreover, if a differential form is $T\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, how could its first argument be $\mathbf x$ ($\in \Bbb R^n$)?

Comment: First, you should be evaluating $\omega$ at the point $t\mathbf x$. Second, it's not literally a cone. You're integrating along the line segment from $\mathbf 0$ to $\mathbf x$, but you have to interpret this correctly. You're "partially integrating" a $(k+1)$-form and ending up with a $k$-form.

Comment: You're of unvaluable help as usual @TedShifrin. I think I've understood, but coul I ask you just to clarify a bit more the expression _"partially integrating"_?

Comment: If $\omega$ is a $1$-form, then there's no question: You end up with a function. But suppose $\omega$ is a $2$-form. Then the integral you get is a function that depends on one tangent vector $\xi$ at $\mathbf x$. In other words, integrating is giving us a $1$-form $\mathcal I\omega$ whose value on $\xi$ is the integral. Work out an explicit example, say $\omega = xy\,dx\wedge dy$ on $\Bbb R^2$, or $\omega = z\,dx\wedge dy$ on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking there was something unusual going on. Thank you one more time @TedShifrin